# Running PhantomJS from PHP using exec()

Tags: php, command-line, phantomjs, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to execute PhantomJS via PHP on my local host (MAMP) on MacOS.

I've installed PhantomJS

```
$ sudo cp phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

and made the file executable

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

When I go to the folder containing my file hello.js and on the command line type

```
$ phantomjs hello.js
```

it works fine.

However, when I try it in PHP on index.php,

```
<?php
    $response = exec('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs hello.js');
    echo $response;
?>
```

I get nothing! What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but you've installed it as sudo and I'm assuming your php script isn't running as sudo. I think you'd need to change the ownership of the phantomjs process to match the same one as php is using

Comment: I always have better luck with backticks. Also try a full path to hello.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
exec('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs path/hello.js');
?>
```

Yes. Sometimes phantomjs don't need full path in some environment without generate any error. However, sometimes it does.

Always use the full path for all argument in the php command.

Did you use the fullpath for hello.js?